# serverless - not able to trigger aws lambda using cloudwatch event

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

Currently my **serverless.yml** file looks like this:

```
service: bbb

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: dev

package:
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - ./bin/**
    
functions:
  ccc:
    handler: bin/executable
    name: my1minutelambda
    role: 
      'Fn::GetAtt':
        - mylambdaexecutionrole
        - Arn
            
resources:
  Resources:
    mylambdaexecutionrole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
         RoleName: my-basiclambdaexec-role
         Description: This is my basiclambdaexecution role
         AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
           Version: "2012-10-17"
           Statement:
             -
               Effect: Allow
               Principal:
                 Service:
                     - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
               Action:
                 - "sts:AssumeRole"
         ManagedPolicyArns:
           - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
    myminschedulerevent: 
      Type: AWS::Events::Rule
      Properties:
        Description: This is my 1 minute rate scheduler.
        Name: my-1-min-trigger-event-scheduler
        ScheduleExpression: rate(1 hour) 
        Targets: 
          - 
            Arn: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111111111111:function:my1minutelambda" #update your a/c Id
            Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
```

command used to deploy: **sls deploy**

After deployment finished, I can see on aws management console that all my resources got created.

BUT **I am not able to see cloudwatch trigger extablishment for my lambda function**.

See below screenshot:

1. CloudWatch Event Rule created successfully. (Target section pointing to my lambda function)

[image]

2. Trigger link not established for my lambda:

[image]

Please let me know what i am missing here. Thank you.

**Update#1:**

After adding following lines (as suggested by Marcin), I am able to see "CloudWatch event".

```
EventsPermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: my1minutelambda
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: events.amazonaws.com
    SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
    SourceArn: !GetAtt myminschedulerevent.Arn
```

**But, I can't see CloudWatch logs!! So, I can't findout if my lambda function is executing. Please see image below:**

[image]

Comment: But does it work? Lambda console sometimes does not show the triggers, even though they work.

Comment: Have you defined an aws permission: `Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission` for cloudwatch event to invoke the lambda in your serverless.yaml file? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html

Comment: @Marcin - I click on "Monitoring "-> "View logs in CloudWatch". But i don't see any "Log stream" for my lambda function.

Comment: @salazarin: I have attached my serverless.yml file.  I think, i have not defined any such permission. Can you please help me with the updated serverless.yml file or the missing 
 yml section? I am pretty new to aws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to **replicate the issue** using `serverless` framework.

To do so I added the following [AWS::Lambda::Permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) to the end of your template:

```
    EventsPermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName: dsfgsdfg # <-- REPLACE this with your function name my1minutelambda
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: events.amazonaws.com
        SourceArn: !GetAtt myminschedulrevent.Arn
```

After adding the permissions, the **console showed the trigger** as expected:

[image]

Comment: With your changes, I am able to see the "EventBridge(CloudWatch Events)" linking.

Comment: But, CloudWatch logs are not showing LogStreams for my lambda function.

Comment: @Jatin You set your rule to trigger once every hour. Maybe have to wait 1 hour, or you modified it?

Comment: i modified it to 1 min

Comment: @Jatin In my tests it works as expected. But obviously I don't know what is your lambda function. My was very basic one.

Comment: @Jatin You can manually invoke it and check if it produces log streams. I assume that you correctly udpated your rule based on the comment " #update your a/c Id"?

Comment: when I manually run my lambda (by clicking on 'Test' button), then, cloud watch log stream got created. I can also see my comment in the log. But, the stream is not being updated after every 1 minute.

Comment: @Marcin: I used AS-IS  SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId' in my serverless. I think this will resolve to actual accountid.

Comment: @Jatin try without `SourceAccount`. It is not a required field.

Comment: @Jatin Not this one. In your ` AWS::Events::Rule` you have comment ` #update your a/c Id`. Have you updated the Arn accordingly?

Comment: @Marcin - Yes I am using my actual accountID at that place.

Comment: If you invoke function manually, using `Test` button in console, does it work?

Comment: @Marcin -- I deleted my cloudformation stack and redeployed. Before sls deploy, I also removed "SourceAccount" from "AWS::Lambda::Permission".  And Now, lambda is working properly. Log streams are updated with the print statements.

Comment: @Jatin Thanks for letting know. I'm glad. I will update the answer to remove the `SourceAccount`.

Comment: @salazarin -  i removed "SourceAccount" from "AWS::Lambda::Permission".  And redeployed using "sls deploy". It is working correctly now. I am getting logs every 1 minute. Thanks. I don;t know what fixed the problem. It is due to commenting "SourceAccount"  or redeployment?  But the problem is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is get a Lambda function to execute on a schedule, the Serverless Framework already includes an event type expressly for that purpose:

```
functions:
  crawl:
    handler: crawl
    events:
      - schedule: rate(2 hours)
      - schedule: cron(0 12 * * ? *)
```

It will set everything up for you with no need to add additional CloudFormation. You can find the documentation here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/#schedule/

Comment: Hi Gareth, Thanks for the quick solution. But, I am specifically trying my own way to achieve my task.  Your solution will work but I am more interested to provide resource information using cloudformation syntax.

Comment: You may find it more useful to use SAM then as SAM is AWS's attempt at a Serverless Framework but uses exclusively Cloud Formation. In that way you avoid the additional work done by the Serverless Framework that may frustrate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScheduledRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: "SphEvent"
      Description: "ScheduledRule"
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(1 hour)"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Arn: !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:lambda-name"
          Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
  PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref "LambdaFunction"
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - "ScheduledRule"
          - "Arn"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.